# Laravel missing parameters

Tags: laravel

I have been trying to build a system that allows the admin to create a task, and once its created a URL should pop-up that directs the admin to the created task.

This worked so far until I crossed the (blockquote below) error

> Missing required parameters for [Route: lesson.continue.task] [URI: lessons/{lessonId}/tasks/{taskId}].

This is the function that creates the URL:

```
 <div class="form-group row">
     <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="level">URL</label>
     @if($task->id) {{ route('lesson.continue.task', $task) }} @endif
 </div>
```

And this is my route:

```
Route::get('/lessons/{lessonId}/tasks/{taskId}', 'LessonController@continueExistingLesson')->name('lesson.continue.task');
```

I've been stuck on this issue for a while now, hopefully someone is able to help me out, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="level">URL </label>
                @if($task->id) {{ route('lesson.continue.task', [$lesson->id,$task->id]) }} @endif
            </div>
```

Comment: This solved the missing parameters error, however it does not recognise the variable lesson.

Comment: @Rb.m: Actually you must need to parameters for this route (i.e taskId and lessionId).so please pass both variables in view file

Comment: @Rb.m: If my answer work for you then please accept my answer